# I have to update SQL value using HttpPost in dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-post

I have an external API resource that I need to use. The API sends me trigger as a post request. What I need to do is get the values, and update the current corresponded record in the SQL. The code that I came up with keeps adding a new value to the database.

```
[HttpPost("status")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CompletionForCreateDto 
completionForCreateDto)
{
    // che ck the model state
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // find the incoming trigger information and map them to the disctionary
    var form = Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var formData = form.Result;
    Dictionary<string, string> ddata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach ( var key in formData.Keys)
    {
        var value = formData[key.ToString()];
        ddata.Add(key, value);
    }

    // find the existed completion by ID
    int id = Int32.Parse(ddata["record"]);
    var completion = await repository.GetCompletion(id);

    completion = mapper.Map<CompletionForCreateDto, Completion>(completionForCreateDto);

    if (completion == null)
        return NotFound();

    // some test values to make sure it works.
    completion.VitalSignBLA = ddata["vital_signs_spring_complete"];
    completion.VitalSignBLADateTime = DateTime.Now;

    // repository.Add(completion); ==> adds value as a new record
    // repository.Update(completion);==> adds value as a new record
    repository.Attach(completion); // ==> adds value as a new record

    // SaveChanges()
    await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Above, first I get the trigger and put them into a dicmtionary so that I can use. Then, I tried to find the existed trigger record in my sql servere using their `record` value. Trigger's `record` and SQL `record` value are the same values. After that, I use some data to test it. Lastly, I used context `Add`, `Update` and `Attach` to update the SQL database. For all cases, the post request is kept adding a new row.

I am new to the dotnet core. I am not sure it this because I used `HttpPost` attribute or the code itself. Any help wpuld be appriciated!

Comment: Did you call SaveChanges(); after Add, Update or Attach?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the post. `await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();` is taking care of it.

Comment: Is the `repository` object an Entity Framework `DbContext`?

Comment: `repository` is the pattern that I use. It includes some basic functionalities such as `Add` `List` etc. It also has the `DbContext` injected. So it has `context` in it.

Comment: are you 100% sure that this line: completion = mapper.Map<CompletionForCreateDto, Completion>(completionForCreateDto); sets the Id and any other members of the PK of the returned instance of Completion?

Comment: Also, be aware that by creating your own instance and then calling Attach or Update, you are basically telling EF: "I have no idea what I'm about to change, so just update everythiing, just in case". It is more efficient to rely on the EF change tracker to track the changes (i.e. modify mapper.map to actually change the Completion instance returned from the database). And 2 other rants: google .ToDictionary and why are you getting the completion from db if you are ignoring it anyway through the line just after?

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea, your comment is correct. The issue is the `mapper`. Please write this to the solution so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause for EF generating an insert statement for an entity when attaching it to a context (Through Attach, Update, Add or by setting its State) is missing values from the PK (most commonly the ID, but the PK can be more complex in other cases) for that entity.

When no PK is present, EF cannot know which entity you are referring to, so it sets the state to New. In your code, I suspect this is generating your issues:

```
var completion = await repository.GetCompletion(id);
completion = mapper.Map<CompletionForCreateDto, Completion>(completionForCreateDto);
```

You are getting some data from the repository, but then generating a new entity through mapper.Map(completionForCreateDto);. I suspect that this code is not setting the PK values, causing your issues. A naive fix would be to set these values after mapper.map. That, or update the mappings to map the values.